# I am creating custom cache type but its not appearing in Cache Management section magento2

Tags: magento2.3, cache, full-page-cache

I have created cache.xml inside app/code/Custom/CacheType/etc/cache.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
    <type name="ansar" translate="label,description" instance="Custom\CacheType\Model\Cache\Type">
        <label>Custom Type Cache</label>
        <description>Custom types cache</description>
    </type>
</config>
```

And i have created Model file in location Custom/CacheType/Model/Cache/Type.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\CacheType\Model\Cache;

class Type extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope
{
    const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = 'ansar';

    const CACHE_TAG = 'ANSAR';

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool)
    {
        parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
    }
}
```

Buts its not displaying in admin section cache management.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing no issue in your code, it could be happening because you have used generalized keywords like type etc. Try this code, it should work.

```
app/code/Custom/CacheType/etc/cache.xml
```

Code would be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
    <type instance="Custom\CacheType\Model\Cache\Ansar" name="ansar_cache_tag" translate="label,description">
        <label>ansar</label>
        <description>Custom types cache</description>
    </type>
</config>
```

and for model file: app/code/Custom/CacheType/Model/Cache/Ansar

```
<?php
namespace Custom\CacheType\Model\Cache;

class Ansar extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope
{

    const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = 'ansar_cache_tag';
    const CACHE_TAG = 'ANSAR_CACHE_TAG';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
    ) {
        parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
    }
}
```

Please try this code, hope this will work